# How can I get current URL in Yii 1.x?

Tags: php, yii

I want to got my current page URL using Yii 1.x.

This is my current page:

```
http://example.com/abc/def
```

and I want to got full URL or last parameters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the current url you can do this.

Outside view files use this:

```
Yii::app()->controller->getId()
Yii::app()->controller->getAction()->getId()
```

Inside view files:

```
$this->getId()
$this->getAction()->getId()
```

Or simply:

```
Yii::app()->request->requestUri
```